# How can I install anything using npm if everything yields the same error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm

Any time I try to install anything via npm, I get this warning:

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'tiletype@0.1.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '0.8.x || 0.10.x' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.15.1', npm: '8.11.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
```

followed by this error (among several other less informative errors)

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/ubuntu/projects/GitHub/AWCPT/opentrees-data/node_modules/mbtiles/node_modules/sqlite3
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
```

This includes `npm install`, `npm install colors`, `npm install sqlite3`, and `npm install tiletype`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There is clearly something wrong with the **tiletype** package.
It requires node v0.8.x or 0.10.x, while you're running v16.15.1.
On top of that, **tiletype** v0.1.0 is [discontinued for quite a while](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiletype?activeTab=readme).

Perhaps, deleting the *node_modules* folder and reinstalling all packages from scratch (`npm i`) would fix it.

If not, check where this package comes from. Is it in your *package.json* or is is installed as a dependency for another package?